# Facebook friends count with Console (without an app)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

How can i count all friends of the current user with Firebug / Developer-Console?

Anyone an idea? Can i use FB JS / PHP SDK in Console?
I tried it with a FQL GET but i cant get the access token.

Answer (score 0):

The access_token will be returned if you call FB.init(). Where you have to pass your App-Id.
So without an App it is not possible because the user has to give your app permission to access on his friendlist.

Comment: I want to count the friends of the User who is logged in in facebook on my Computer - this has nothing to do with an app. I just want a request for the friends of the current user.

Comment: If you want to get  information ab out anything in facebook... You habe to Register your Website or whatever AS an facebook APP.. That is what facebook calls Websites with open graph functionality